# Jquery/CSS Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code working apart from the icon when you close the panel. It should be a cross when the panel closes and a minus when the panel is expanded and shown on the screen.

**I have been told I cannot change the HTML** however I can change the CSSand/or the Jquery.
Can someone please help me with the icon? I just need to work out that the icon changes to a plus when you go to minimize it.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.accordioncollapse').hide(); //added

  $(".accordion-heading").click(function() {

  $(this).find('.accordion-toggle').addClass('collapsed'); //added

  $(this).parent().addClass('active').find('.panel2').slideToggle('fast');
  $(".accordion-heading").not(this).parent().removeClass('active').find('.panel2').slideUp('fast');

  $(".accordion-heading").not(this).find('.accordion-toggle').removeClass('collapsed'); //added
  
  }); 
  
});
```

```css
.panel1 {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.accordion-default {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
}

.accordion-heading>a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.875;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
}

.accordion-heading>a:hover,
.accordion-heading>a:active,
.accordion-heading>a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #D0006F;
}

.accordion-body {
  margin-left: 2px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.accordion-toggle {
  padding-left: 2px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
}

.accordion-toggle::before,
.accordion-toggle::after {
  right: 5px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 2px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  background-color: #D0006F;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}

.accordion-toggle::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  opacity: 1;
}

.accordion-toggle.collapsed::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion-toggle.collapsed::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel1" id="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-default">
    <div class="accordion-heading">​
      <a class="accordion-toggle " aria-expanded="false" href="#collapseOne" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse">Heading1</a> </div>
    <div class="panel2 accordioncollapse collapse" id="collapseOne" aria-expanded="false">
      <div class="accordion-body"> Collapsible Content #1 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-default">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" aria-expanded="false" href="#collapseTwo" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse">Heading2</a> </div>
    <div class="panel2 accordioncollapse collapse" id="collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false">
      <div class="accordion-body"> Collapsible Content #2 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-default">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" aria-expanded="false" href="#collapseThree" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse">Heading3</a> </div>
    <div class="panel2 accordioncollapse collapse" id="collapseThree" aria-expanded="false">
      <div class="accordion-body"> Collapsible Content #3 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**At the moment the code that does work that we need to keep is:**
Only open one panel at a time
Thanks in advance,
Clare

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to change `addClass` to `toggleClass` - try the snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.accordioncollapse').hide(); //added

  $(".accordion-heading").click(function() {

  $(this).find('.accordion-toggle').toggleClass('collapsed'); //added

  $(this).parent().addClass('active').find('.panel2').slideToggle('fast');
  $(".accordion-heading").not(this).parent().removeClass('active').find('.panel2').slideUp('fast');

  $(".accordion-heading").not(this).find('.accordion-toggle').removeClass('collapsed'); //added
  
  }); 
  
});
```

```css
.panel1 {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.accordion-default {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
}

.accordion-heading>a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.875;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
}

.accordion-heading>a:hover,
.accordion-heading>a:active,
.accordion-heading>a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #D0006F;
}

.accordion-body {
  margin-left: 2px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.accordion-toggle {
  padding-left: 2px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: left;
}

.accordion-toggle::before,
.accordion-toggle::after {
  right: 5px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 2px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  background-color: #D0006F;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}

.accordion-toggle::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  opacity: 1;
}

.accordion-toggle.collapsed::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion-toggle.collapsed::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel1" id="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-default">
    <div class="accordion-heading">​
      <a class="accordion-toggle " aria-expanded="false" href="#collapseOne" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse">Heading1</a> </div>
    <div class="panel2 accordioncollapse collapse" id="collapseOne" aria-expanded="false">
      <div class="accordion-body"> Collapsible Content #1 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-default">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" aria-expanded="false" href="#collapseTwo" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse">Heading2</a> </div>
    <div class="panel2 accordioncollapse collapse" id="collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false">
      <div class="accordion-body"> Collapsible Content #2 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-default">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" aria-expanded="false" href="#collapseThree" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse">Heading3</a> </div>
    <div class="panel2 accordioncollapse collapse" id="collapseThree" aria-expanded="false">
      <div class="accordion-body"> Collapsible Content #3 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Dan - looks like it's working - I'll have to test more thoroughly in my SharePoint site - internet here is now flaky! Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Hi Dan, For some reason when I put this code in it does the opposite of what it should i.e when I click the first heading the toggle on the other headings change to a minus instead of the active heading changing to a minus (the panel does open up as it should which is good). The code snippet above works perfectly. Not sure why it's not translating to my share point environment.

Comment: Are there any other differences in the code that you identified?